# Refresh en multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación en donde estoy utilizando 4 multiselect uno depende de otro para llenarse y el llenado lo hago con jquery, el primer multiselect lo lleno con campos directos, y una vez que elijo alguna opción o varias, me llena el segundo multiselect sin problemas, pero cuando quiero seleccionar algo del segundo multiselect ya no me está tomando el valor que seleccioné, me manda null, dejo el código del llenado que hago en los multiselect:

```
$("#multiselect2id").append('<option value="' + 0 + '"></option>');
$.each(Result.objFiltro, function (index, value) {
    $("#multiselect2id")
        .append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Nombre + '</option>')
        .multiselect('destroy')
        .multiselect();
});
```

Comment: Hola, estas usando [esta](http://loudev.com/#demos) librería? o cuál?

Comment: Estoy utilizando jquery.multiselect.min.js, ya intenté aplicarle el refresh también pero al momento de seleccionar algo no lo está mandando a la acción del controlador.

Comment: Sandra, deja el código de como estas intentando aplicarle el refresh, a más completa sea la información que dejas más posible es que alguien te pueda ayudar

Comment: Lo borré porque no me funcionaba pero era así $("#multiselect2id).multiselect('refresh'), el llenado lo hago con ajax, intento pasarle un objeto json, y al ejecutar la aplicación lo muestra, el problema es que no sé cómo obtener los valores de lo seleccionado para que me pueda llenar el multiselect siguiente.

Comment: tengo un ejemplo en vanillaJS https://jsfiddle.net/elporfirio/2ea6v35c/  pero en si solo te falta el evento "onchange" para tomar el valor cuando cambie uno :) u otro